# Divisibility of numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Find all positive integers $x,y$ such that $2x+7y$ divides $7x+2y$.

I somehow managed to show that $x$ is greater than $y$. But couldn't proceed further.

Comment: If $x > y$, which integer values could $\frac{7x+2y}{2x+7y}$ possibly attain?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:  $7x+2y=(2x+7y)k\implies(7-2k)x=(7k-2)y$.  If $x$, $y$, and $k$ are all positive integers, how large can $k$ be?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is all x,y such that x=y or x=4y or x=19y. So, your question has infinitely many solutions.